# Preventing Visual Studio Test Explorer from discovering tests in shared .NET Standard library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit

I have 3 test projects, with the following dependency hierarchy:

```
Tests.Common (.NET Standard library)
    Tests.DotNetCore (.NET Core library)
    Tests.Wpf (.NET Framework library)
```

The idea is to define the test methods as calling into a `RunTests` method in `Tests.Common`:

```
// using xUnit
// using System.Linq.Expressions
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

namespace Tests.Common {
    public class TestBase {
        protected virtual void RunTest(Expression expr, string result) { ... }
    }
    public class Constructed {
        [Fact]
        public void ConstructBinary() => 
            RunTest(
                Add(Constant(5), Constant(42)),
                "5 + 42"
            );
    }
}
```

and then in `Tests.Wpf` I can test the same expressions against UI-only VM classes, by overriding the `RunTests` method:

```
// using ExpressionToString.Wpf

namespace Tests.Wpf {
    public class Constructed : Tests.Common.Constructed {
        public override void RunTest(Expression expr, string result) {
            var vm = new ExpressionVM(expr);
            // at this point, all I want to test is that the VM class is created successfully
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that Visual Studio Test Explorer discovers the test methods in `Tests.Common`, even though xUnit tests in a .NET Standard library cannot be run; [they require a platform-specific library](https://xunit.net/docs/why-no-netstandard) (this is why I have a `Tests.DotNetCore` test project, and an additional inheritance chain there.)

**How can I prevent Visual Studio Test Explorer from displaying the tests in the .NET Standard library?**

Comment: Did you try to declare the base class in `Common` as `abstract`?

Comment: Make `Common` class an `abstract`!

Comment: @acelent Using `abstract` works. Do you want to write it up as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I've done it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the base class in the `Common` project as `abstract`.

That should make the test explorer exclude the base class as a tests class, and recognize the test methods in all descendant classes.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not set [Fact] attributes on them, but only on the actual implementations.**

Test discovery logic is based on matching [Fact] attributes on methods with xUnit supported signatures in test projects. Do not use [Fact] attributes in top level implementation but only in the overriden methods which are used for running actual tests. This will prevent their detection at any level in both Visual Studio Test Explorer and in xUnit runners. If want to directly reuse top level method override it and call base.RunTest() in the body.

Comment: The inherited classes (`Tests.DotNetCore.Constructed` and `Tests.Wpf.Constructed`) don't have any implementation; they simply inherit the implementation from the base class (`Tests.Common.Constructed`). This is a major benefit for me, as I don't have to redeclare all the test methods in both inherited classes (`Tests.DotNetCore.Constructed` and `Tests.Wpf.Constructed`).

Comment: Yes, I understand but due to the xUnit built in test discovery logic there is no clean way to prevent Test Explorer and xUnit to discover these methods. The solution is to override this top level method, set [Fact] attribute on it and simply call base implementation in the body. Visual Studio has code helpers which will generate overrides semi-automatically. Otherwise, sorry but to me it seems very hard to solve. Best way to understand these limitations is to look into xUnit test discovery source code and anyway I am a sporadic contributor to the xUnit test discovery functionality.